# what is the character for new line in asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

what is the character for a new line in asp

Comment: Classic asp? ASP.NET? Where _exactly_ do you need the new line?

Comment: ASP is not a language. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 10):

If you want a line break between HTML elements or text, you need to use a `<BR />` tag.

If you want to want the HTML *source* to have a line break, you need to output one - in classic ASP, using vbscript that would be `vbCrLf`. In .NET you should use `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been looking everywhere for vbCrLf (I'm using ASP to create an email, which doesn't recognize html).

Answer (score 3):

For future-archeologists, the correct answer in javascript/jscript is \n and it's vbCrLf in vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML to get a new line use the `<br>` tag.